# Hudson on Dreamhost

Tags: linux, debian, vps, hudson, dreamhost

Have you successfully installed Hudson on a Dreamhost VPS? If you have, what are the steps to make it run continuously, even if the server restarts? They run debian on the servers.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/) is an manual how to install Jenkins/hudson on debian.

Main page [jenkins-ci.org](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm voting up your answer - but I am specifically asking for Dreamhost VPS-specific implementation.

Comment: Do you have a complete vps? With root access?

Comment: @Stony Yes, I do have a VPS with root access.

Comment: so then whats the problem? Then follow the installation guide. When you insert the source they load all depencies.

Comment: Does that restart jenkins automatically too?

Comment: yes when you install it over the repo then its inserted as init script. then you can start over /etc/init.d/jenkins restart something like this. And when you install it over the repo you get updates, too.